# MVEL Include Template

Tags: java, mvel

I want include MVEL into another MVEL file , I tried to use the @Include but it doesn't work for me,

Can anyone please suggest me that how to use MVEL in another MVEL file

Here is My code

```
Dear @{FIRST_NAME}, 
Hello How are you??    
@include('./Footer.txt')
```

Here Footer.txt is another file which contains sample text

```
Regards,
Satish
```

The output that I am getting as

```
Dear John
Hello How are you??
@include('../Footer.txt'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there is some correction in include

It should be like `@include{'Footer.txt'}`

Comment: now I am getting another problem that '.\Footer.txt': file not found even though that file in the same directory